# Sorting blog posts by date, conversion failed

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, pdo

I am building a blog and im trying to do so that i can sort by year and month, however i get the error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string.1

Obviously i am using Microsoft SQL server just to make it clear.

i have sorted that when showing the post by doing like this

> date_format( new DateTime($postdate['5']), 'd M Y, H:i' );

so how do i implement a thing like that on this piece?

```
if (isset($_GET['year_month']))
{
    $bdate = $_GET['year_month'];               
    $tsql4 = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blog_date=:bdate ORDER BY blogID DESC"; 
    $stmt5 = $conn->prepare($tsql4);
    $stmt5->execute (array($bdate));
    while($postdate = $stmt5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) )
    { 
     here i post the $postdate rows
```

i have tried some SELECT convert blablabla but havent gotten it to work..
The dates is stored in the db like 2016-01-01 HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $postdate['5'] equals to $_GET['year_month'] then you can use this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['year_month']))
{
    // $_GET['year_month'] looks like '2016-02';
    list($year, $month) = @explode('-', $_GET['year_month']);
    $day = 1;
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    $datetime->setDate($year, $month , $day);
    $datetime->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $bdate_start = date_format($datetime, 'Y-m-d H:m:s');
    $datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    $bdate_finish = date_format($datetime, 'Y-m-d H:m:s');

    $tsql4 = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blog_date BETWEEN :bdate_start AND :bdate_finish ORDER BY blogID DESC"; 
    $stmt5 = $conn->prepare($tsql4);
    $stmt5->execute (array($bdate_start, $bdate_finish));
    while($postdate = $stmt5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) )
    { 
     here i post the $postdate rows
```

Comment: the date_format( new DateTime($postdate['5']), 'd M Y, H:i' ); row comes after the while, im trying to access the site by like mysite.com/index.php?year_month=2016-02, With your line i just get a blank space once i put ' in front and after Y-m-d H:m:s

Comment: i think i have to do some kind of conversion on the SELECT row, however im not sure since im kind of an rookie...

Comment: I improve answer to process your input in form like this '2016-02'

Comment: Thanks for the try, but i still get a blank page :/

Comment: i find alot on google like this SELECT * FROM DATE_SAMPLE 
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10),SAMPLE_DATE,120) = '2003-04-09' but i cant get anything like that working either tho

Comment: If your data in form of 2016-01-01 HH:MM:SS then we create appropriate format from '2016-02' to '2016-02-01 15:02:11'. But in your query `SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blog_date=:bdate ORDER BY blogID DESC` you sorting by blogID for WHERE date equal to '2016-02-01 15:02:11'. If you want to sort by date you can run query `SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER by blog_date DESC`.

Comment: Yea, but i want to show only posts made in januari or februari etc, and sorted by blogID, thats the problem

Comment: It's not the problem. I will update answer for finding posts in february

Comment: Try new version with appropriate working with month interval

Comment: Wohoo big ups man, the only wierd thing is that if i check February the first of march shows, i guess it has something to do with that it was leap year? the march post that shows in februari was posted 01 Mar 2016, 00:01 might have something with that?

Comment: No, it's php working with timezones. Add string `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` before working with DateTime

Comment: Ah well, just changed the time abit in the DB and it worked like a charm, Thanks alot for helping me out i appreciate it alot! :) gonna read up abit on what @explode etc does.

Comment: explode just split string into array by separating symbol, in our case this symbol is '-'